# Fixed Frame [/laser] does not exist

Tags: ros, rviz, laser, frame, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my launch file

```
 <launch>
    <node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo_node">
        <remap from="/scan" to="/base_scan" />
     </node>
 </launch>
```

Why rviz says Fixed Frame [/laser] does not exist?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10655/fixed-frame-%5B/laser%5D-does-not-exist/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nobody is publishing tf information from the /laser frame.
I guess, you input the fixed frame manually in the box and you also see the laser, so that should be fine.

Problems will arise if you have data in other frames.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-20**:
It's only if you don't have tf information, you can hardcode something. The better way is to publish tf information as you did!

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-20**:
Uh,I know I can choose from Fixed Frame combo,but why I need to input some text(different than text which can be choose) in Fixed Frame box? Is it useful for something?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-20**:
Usually the Fixed Frame has a combo containing the frames send by tf for you to choose. If nobody publishes you can still just input anything (e.g. /laser)

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-19**:
Thank you~I don't know what means of 'input the fixed frame manually in the box', but I found that when I add tf node with /laser transform,it works!

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-04-11**:
The option target frame is missing in groovy's rviz. What can be done instead?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-11**:
This is a different question. Please open a new one.